# Изъять данные при нажатии на ListView

Tags: java, android

Есть ListView, в него вложен layout.  Получается список.
По нажатию я могу изъять `id`, но как изъять оттуда данные, которые записанные в `TextView`?

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            curItem = id;
            view.
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В метод `onItemLongClick()`вам передается вторым параметром View view. **Это view нажатого пункта ListView.** Из него можно и получить TextView по id с помощью `findViewById(id)`. Примерно вот так это будет выглядеть:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3){
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idВашегоTextView);
}
```

А затем всё просто: `textView.getText().toString();`

Так же у адаптера есть метод getItem(position), который вернет по позиции данные текущего айтема. Этот способ наиболее эффективен.

Comment: получать данные из виджетов не очень хорошая идея. у адаптера есть метод `getItem(position)`, который вернет по позиции данные текущего айтема

Comment: @pavlofff дополнил ответ, спасибо.